# Does surjective map induce surjective map on Hewitt real compactifications?

Tags: compactifications, stone-cech-compactification

Let $\beta X$ be the Stone-Čech compactification  and $\upsilon X$ be the
Hewitt real compactification of a completely regular space $X$.

It is well
known that any continuous surjective map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ induces
surjective map $\beta \left( f\right) :\beta X\rightarrow \beta Y$.
Similarly,  Is the induced map $\upsilon \left( f\right) :\upsilon X\rightarrow
\upsilon Y$ surjective?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  It is known that the continuous image of a realcompact space is not necessarily realcompact (I don't know a specific example offhand, but this appears as Problem 432 in Tkachuk's C_p-theory problem book).

So let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous surjection, where $X$ is realcompact and $Y$ is not.  Since $X$ is realcompact, $\upsilon(X) = X$, so $\operatorname{im}(\upsilon(f)) = \operatorname{im}(f) = Y$.  But since $Y$ is not realcompact, $\upsilon(Y) \supsetneq Y$, and so $\upsilon(f)$ is not surjective.

Comment: Actually, what I want to know whether the orbit map $\pi :X\rightarrow X/G$ induces surjective map between their real compactification spaces. The orbit space of a realcompact space is also realcompact. (R. Engelking, 3.11G.). Also, the orbit map is perfect open map.

Comment: I see - sorry, I don't have any particular insight into that case.  Hopefully someone else will be able to answer.